# How to reset SQL Server Configuration Manager Windows To Original Windows Configuration (as if it had been newly installed)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been looking at a lot of articles, and still cannot come up with an answer to the following. I am running Windows 10 workstation, and have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer.

This problem refers to SQL Server Configuration Manager, not SQL Server Management console.

Somehow, I managed to configure the view of SQL Server Configuration Manager (see attached picture), so that only Protocols for MSSQLSERVER window appears.[image] I want to see the full series of views from the root.

How do I reset things back to the default? By this question, I mean that I can no longer see all the tab choices.

Now, the windows on which the application opens is the Protocols for MSSQLSERVER window. I somehow advanced to a new window using the open new window directive. When I went to close the application, I was prompted with a prompt I didn't understand, and when I saved and restarted the application found I could no longer see all the choices that exist above the Protocols window.

I tried re-installing, and that did not work.